# Storing Spotify token in flask session using spotipy?

Tags: python, html, flask, spotipy

I may have a bad understanding of how the flask session works, but I am trying to generate a Spotify API access token using [SpotiPY](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with the Authorization Code Flow, and store it in Flask's session storage.

The program doesn't seem to be able to store it, and therefore later runs in to an error when trying to call it. Here is a visual explanation with images and captions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvhQG.jpg

Here is the main server script:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, session, make_response,session,redirect
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
from credentz import *
app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = SSK

@app.route("/")
def verify():
    session.clear()
    session['toke'] = util.prompt_for_user_token("", scope='playlist-modify-private,playlist-modify-public,user-top-read', client_id=CLI_ID, client_secret=CLI_SEC, redirect_uri="http://127.0.0.1:5000/index")
    return redirect("/index")

@app.route("/index")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/go", methods=['POST'])
def go():
    data=request.form
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=session['toke'])
    response = sp.current_user_top_artists(limit=data['num_tracks'], time_range=data['time_range'])
    return render_template("results.html",data=data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and here are the two html files: [Index.html](https://pastebin.com/Qubx8uEr), [Results.html](https://pastebin.com/qcRgcSNr)

Some things worth noting:

- `Credentz` stores all of the private info including `SSK`, `CLI_SEC`, and `CLI_ID`.
- The spotipy request works fine if I do it in a non-flask environment with no web-browser interaction.
- I am able to store other things in the session storage, and call it back later, just not the access token for some reason.
- My best guess is that the page doesn't have time to store it before the Spotify api redirects the page, not sure though.

Any help is really appreciated, Thank You!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right, spotify is redirecting you before the token can be added therefore ending the execution of that function. So you need to add a callback step to grab the authentication token after you've been redirected.

Spotitpy's util.prompt_for_user_token method is not designed to be used in a web server so your best best is to implement the auth flow your self and then use spotipy once you have the token. Luckily the spotify authorization flow is pretty simple and easy to implement.

Method 1: Implementing auth flow our self:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, session, make_response,session,redirect
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
from credentz import *
import requests
app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = SSK

API_BASE = 'https://accounts.spotify.com'

# Make sure you add this to Redirect URIs in the setting of the application dashboard
REDIRECT_URI = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api_callback"

SCOPE = 'playlist-modify-private,playlist-modify-public,user-top-read'

# Set this to True for testing but you probably want it set to False in production.
SHOW_DIALOG = True

# authorization-code-flow Step 1. Have your application request authorization; 
# the user logs in and authorizes access
@app.route("/")
def verify():
    auth_url = f'{API_BASE}/authorize?client_id={CLI_ID}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}&scope={SCOPE}&show_dialog={SHOW_DIALOG}'
    print(auth_url)
    return redirect(auth_url)

@app.route("/index")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

# authorization-code-flow Step 2.
# Have your application request refresh and access tokens;
# Spotify returns access and refresh tokens
@app.route("/api_callback")
def api_callback():
    session.clear()
    code = request.args.get('code')

    auth_token_url = f"{API_BASE}/api/token"
    res = requests.post(auth_token_url, data={
        "grant_type":"authorization_code",
        "code":code,
        "redirect_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:5000/api_callback",
        "client_id":CLI_ID,
        "client_secret":CLI_SEC
        })

    res_body = res.json()
    print(res.json())
    session["toke"] = res_body.get("access_token")

    return redirect("index")


# authorization-code-flow Step 3.
# Use the access token to access the Spotify Web API;
# Spotify returns requested data
@app.route("/go", methods=['POST'])
def go():
    data = request.form    
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=session['toke'])
    response = sp.current_user_top_artists(limit=data['num_tracks'], time_range=data['time_range'])
    return render_template("results.html", data=data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

On the other hand we can cheat a little bit and use the methods that spotipy itself is using in order to save us some code.

Method 2: Implementing auth flow (along with custom token management) using spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth method:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, session, make_response,session,redirect
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
from credentz import *
import time
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = SSK

API_BASE = 'https://accounts.spotify.com'

# Make sure you add this to Redirect URIs in the setting of the application dashboard
REDIRECT_URI = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api_callback"

SCOPE = 'playlist-modify-private,playlist-modify-public,user-top-read'

# Set this to True for testing but you probaly want it set to False in production.
SHOW_DIALOG = True


# authorization-code-flow Step 1. Have your application request authorization; 
# the user logs in and authorizes access
@app.route("/")
def verify():
    # Don't reuse a SpotifyOAuth object because they store token info and you could leak user tokens if you reuse a SpotifyOAuth object
    sp_oauth = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(client_id = CLI_ID, client_secret = CLI_SEC, redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI, scope = SCOPE)
    auth_url = sp_oauth.get_authorize_url()
    print(auth_url)
    return redirect(auth_url)

@app.route("/index")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

# authorization-code-flow Step 2.
# Have your application request refresh and access tokens;
# Spotify returns access and refresh tokens
@app.route("/api_callback")
def api_callback():
    # Don't reuse a SpotifyOAuth object because they store token info and you could leak user tokens if you reuse a SpotifyOAuth object
    sp_oauth = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(client_id = CLI_ID, client_secret = CLI_SEC, redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI, scope = SCOPE)
    session.clear()
    code = request.args.get('code')
    token_info = sp_oauth.get_access_token(code)

    # Saving the access token along with all other token related info
    session["token_info"] = token_info


    return redirect("index")

# authorization-code-flow Step 3.
# Use the access token to access the Spotify Web API;
# Spotify returns requested data
@app.route("/go", methods=['POST'])
def go():
    session['token_info'], authorized = get_token(session)
    session.modified = True
    if not authorized:
        return redirect('/')
    data = request.form
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=session.get('token_info').get('access_token'))
    response = sp.current_user_top_tracks(limit=data['num_tracks'], time_range=data['time_range'])

    # print(json.dumps(response))

    return render_template("results.html", data=data)

# Checks to see if token is valid and gets a new token if not
def get_token(session):
    token_valid = False
    token_info = session.get("token_info", {})

    # Checking if the session already has a token stored
    if not (session.get('token_info', False)):
        token_valid = False
        return token_info, token_valid

    # Checking if token has expired
    now = int(time.time())
    is_token_expired = session.get('token_info').get('expires_at') - now < 60

    # Refreshing token if it has expired
    if (is_token_expired):
        # Don't reuse a SpotifyOAuth object because they store token info and you could leak user tokens if you reuse a SpotifyOAuth object
        sp_oauth = spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(client_id = CLI_ID, client_secret = CLI_SEC, redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI, scope = SCOPE)
        token_info = sp_oauth.refresh_access_token(session.get('token_info').get('refresh_token'))

    token_valid = True
    return token_info, token_valid

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Either method is equally valid in my opinion, just go with whichever method you find easier to understand.

Make sure that you update the authorized Redirect URIs in your spotify application dashboard.

See the spotify docs for more info: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow